# Convergence of sequence and algebraic limit theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is to show that the statement is true or false, and if true give proof and if false give counter example.
**(a)** If $\left( {{a_n}} \right) \to 0$ and $\left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right) \to 0$, then $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to a$. 
Approach: This statement is false. Since $\left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right) \to 0$, therefore I can write, 
$\lim {b_n} - {a_n} = \lim {b_n} - \lim {a_n}$, using algebraic limit theorem. This will give, 
$\lim {b_n} = \lim {a_n}$. Hence it can be concluded $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to 0$ and not $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to a$. Counter example can be if I choose, ${b_n} = \left( {{1 \over {2n}}} \right)$ and ${a_n} = \left( {{1 \over n}} \right)$. Then $\left( {{a_n}} \right) \to 0$ and $\left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right) \to 0$, and $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to 0$. Problem with this example is when I choose ${b_n} = \left( {{1 \over {2n}}} \right)$ I am already saying that $\left( {b_n} \right) \to 0$. Am I correct in proving the given statement false, if yes, what could be better example to it. 
**(b)** If $\left( {{a_n}} \right) \to 0$ and  $\left| {{b_n} - b} \right| \le {a_n}$ for all $n \in N$, then $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to b$. 
Approach: Considering $\left| {{b_n} - b} \right| \le {a_n}$ and algebraic limit theorem and triangle inequality I can write, 
$\left| {{b_n} - b} \right| \le \left| {{b_n}} \right| + \left| b \right|$ 
$\left| {{b_n}} \right| + \left| b \right| \le {a_n}$ (will this be true) 
 If its true how do I arrive at $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to b$.

**UPDATE:**

For **(a)** I can write ${b_n} = \left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right) + {a_n}$ Now since ${a_n}$ and $\left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right)$ are convergent I can conclude that ${{b_n}}$ converges and converges to $0$. Then proceed with the above explanation that I gave.
For **(b)** since $({a_n}) \to 0$ so I can take $\left| {{a_n} - 0} \right|$ as small as I would like it to be. If I choose some $N_1$ such that 
 $\left| {{a_n} - 0} \right| < \varepsilon $ whenever $n \ge {N_1}$. Now when $n \ge {N_1}$, I can say 
 $\left| {{a_n} - 0} \right| < \varepsilon $ or $\left| {a_n} \right| < \varepsilon $ and this would mean that 
 $\left| {{b_n} - b} \right| < \varepsilon $ for all $n \ge {N_1}$. 
 Therefore by definition of convergence $\left( {{b_n}} \right) \to b$. 
Have I aced it??

Comment: $\lim b_n-a_n\neq \lim b_n-\lim a_n$ because the convergence of $b_n$ is not yet established, so the notation $\lim b_n$ makes no sense

Comment: Looking  at the first statement, I feel there is something incorrect. Are you sure it's not $a_n \to a$? Of course, as stated, unless $a = 0$, the statement is false (you also have to prove that $\lim b_n$ exists). The second statement can be proved directly from the definition of convergence of a sequence (pick $\epsilon > 0$,and $n$ large enough so that $|a_n| \leq \epsilon$).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг In the problem its given $\left( {{a_n}} \right) \to 0$ and not $\left( {{a_n}} \right) \to a$. This means what I have done is incorrect.

Comment: Leave the first question, it seems correct, all you need to show is that $\lim b_n$ exists. Was  the explanation of the second question clear?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг. Yes. I am trying to establish what you have suggested. when I will come up with an answer I will update.

Comment: Definitely. Please take your time. This is a basic question, the more time you spend on it,the better your understanding.

Comment: @NickLiu if $\lim \left( {{b_n} - {a_n}} \right) = 0$ then it does not necessarily mean that $\lim {b_n} = \lim {a_n}$. I was trying to find two sequence such that the subtraction of these sequence converges to zero but both of the sequences individually converging to different point. Can you help me in finding such two sequences ?

Comment: The first question can be handled by using $b_{n} = (b_{n} - a_{n}) + a_{n}$ and the second one is done by noting that $b - a_{n} \leq b_{n} \leq b + a_{n}$ and then use the squeeze theorem.